# Calculate the difference between two hours on PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Given a table as the following:

```
    create table meetings(
    id integer primary key,
    start_time varchar,
    end_time varchar
)
```

Considering that the string stored in this table follow the format 'HH:MM' and have a 24 hours format, is there a command on PostgreSQL 9.4 that I can cast fields to time, calculate the difference between them, and return a single result of the counting of full hours available?

e.g: `start_time: '08:00' - end_time: '12:00'`
Result must be `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, assuming that you are working with clock values (both of them belonging to the same day), I would guess you can do this

```
(clock_to::time - clock_from::time) as duration
```

Allow me to leave you a ready to run example:

```
with cte as (
  select '4:00'::varchar as clock_from, '14:00'::varchar as clock_to
)
select (clock_to::time - clock_from::time) as duration
from cte
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer that I was looking for!